# Why isn't the minus sign cancelled in this change of variables?

Tags: integration, fluid-dynamics, change-of-variable

This integral comes from fluid dynamics, specifically it's the fluid velocity when said fluid is subject to small perturbations. Regardless, my question is mathematical, and probably trivial, but I'm kind of scratching my head at it.

Consider:

$$\vec{v}(\vec{x},t)=-\hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0}\int\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}dt \ ; \ \xi=\hat{n}\cdot\vec{x}-ut$$

My notes state that, therefore:

$$\vec{v}(\vec{x},t)= -\hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0u}\int\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}d\xi=-\hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0u}P'(\hat{n}\cdot \vec{x}-ut)$$

But it seems to me that the change of variables should be $d\xi=-udt\rightarrow dt=-d\xi/u$ and that therefore the solution should be the same, but without the minus sign. Why isn't this the case?

Comment: I'm concerned about why you haven't written $p'(\hat{n}\cdot x-ut)$ instead - where did the $n$ go>

Comment: @FShrike Ah, well, I guess I just wrote the dot product as $x$, I can edit it.

Comment: Hint: make your limits of integration explicit.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Well if I'm integrating from a time $0$ to a time $t$, then the limits would change to $x$ and $x-ut$. But either way, my end result is positive (assuming that the initial velocity, corresponding to $t=0$, is $0$).

Comment: @agaminon right, but are the limits of integration of the second integral $\int_x^{x-ut}$ or $\int_{x-ut}^x$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog The correct derivation comes from the second one, but the first one is what makes intuitive sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the minus sign becomes more clear if you leave the limits of integration explicit. You are correct that the sign should go away after the initial change of variables:
$$
-\hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0}\int_0^t\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}dt' = \hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0u}\int_x^{x-ut}\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}d\xi.
$$
However, if we are considering $u > 0$, the upper limit is smaller than the lower limit. This may be undesirable, and can be fixed by swapping the limits of integration, which introduces a minus sign:
$$
-\hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0}\int_0^t\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}dt' = \hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0u}\int_x^{x-ut}\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}d\xi= - \hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0u}\int_{x-ut}^x\frac{dP'(\xi)}{d\xi}d\xi.
$$
Note that having or not having the minus sign can be correct, provided that you use the correct limits of integration. Leaving integrals as indefinite leads to confusion if you're not careful.

Also, in general, the sign in the change of variables doesn't matter for definite integrals. If it's negative, you end up having to swap the limits of integration, which cancels the minus sign. This is also essentially why in multivariate integrals, the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant is used for the volume element rather than the signed value.

Comment: But if you then evaluate the third integral, shouldn't you get:

$$v=-\hat{n}\frac{1}{\rho_0u}\left[P'(x)-P'(x-ut) \right] $$

And then, treating the initial velocity as $0$, shouldn't the result still be positive?

Comment: @agaminon Hmm, that's a good point. It's possible the notes have a sign error. It's possibly the most pernicious thing in all of mathematics.

Comment: I've also noticed that if you start by "absorbing the minus sign", you get (i'll ignore constants for brevity):

$$\int_t^0 \frac{dP'}{d\xi}dt=\left[P'(x)-P'(x-ut) \right]$$

Which is the correct result. I don't really get what's going on here.

EDIT: Woops, ignore this, I forgot the minus sign in the change of variables.